# Collapse strings in the same group into one html with dplyr, paste(),

Tags: html, r, dplyr

I want to express the link and link name strings in my data.frame into html for each group.  If I start with

```
foo <- data.frame(the_url = c("http://www.link1.com", "http://www.link2.com", "http://www.link3.com",
                      "http://www.link4.com", "http://www.link5.com", "http://www.link6.com"),
              name = c("Link 1", "Link 2", "Link 3", "Link 4", "Link 5", "Link 6"),
              the_group = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))
```

and want to get to this as a final object,

```
data.frame(the_group = c(1, 2, 3),
       html = c("<a href= \"http://www.link1.com\">Link 1</a>", 
                "<a href= \"http://www.link2.com\">Link 2</a><br/><a href= \"http://www.link3.com\">Link 3</a>",
                "<a href= \"http://www.link4.com\">Link 4</a><br/><a href= \"http://www.link5.com\">Link 5</a><br/><a href= \"http://www.link6.com\">Link 6</a>")
       )
```

How would I do so? Is dplyr the right tool for this?

I can show my progress of getting each row to show as an individual html link, now I need to collapse them down by group.

```
foo %>% mutate(html = paste0('<a href= "', the_url, '">', name, '</a>')) %>%
  group_by(the_group) #%>% 
# should I use something like summarize(x = paste(THING, collapse = "<br/>") ? 
#I want to paste and collapse all of the url and name pairs into one html string with a line break between pairs.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_by %>% summarize`; `paste0` with `collapse` parameter can be used to paste strings in a vector together:

```
foo %>% 
    group_by(the_group) %>% 
    summarise(html = paste0(sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', the_url, name), collapse = "<br/>"))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  the_group                                                                                                                                          html
#      <dbl>                                                                                                                                         <chr>
#1         1                                                                                                 "<a href=\"http://www.link1.com\">Link 1</a>"
#2         2                                                 "<a href=\"http://www.link2.com\">Link 2</a><br/><a href=\"http://www.link3.com\">Link 3</a>"
#3         3 "<a href=\"http://www.link4.com\">Link 4</a><br/><a href=\"http://www.link5.com\">Link 5</a><br/><a href=\"http://www.link6.com\">Link 6</a>"
```